# Fire Event from within Outlook 2007 Add In which is picked up by external application

Tags: c#, .net, events, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Addin which does some processing of the Outlook mailboxes. On processing an email it fires an **MailProcessed** Event, if it couldn't process the email it fires **MailProcessFail** Event.

Now I have an external service which is running. It calls the add-in every 60 seconds to start processing the emails. It needs to listen to the custom events fired from the Add In and then take action.

Now I have tried implementing this with a simple c# **Event**, but when it gets to the following code

```
this.OutLookPlugin.MailProcessed += this.MailProcessSuccess;
```

It throws the following Exception. ArgumentException: value does not fall within the expected range.

Has anyone managed to throw a custom event from within an Outlook addin and listen to it from an external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think what you are trying to do is possible.  You would need to call a method on a windows service (or something similar) that can handle the call.

Because the two programs are running on different threads they can't pick up each others events.

Comment: What so I would have to do an invoke?

Comment: In the end I decided not to try and pass events since it just didn't work. It also wouldn't allow complex information to be passed out of the Plugin.